# get audio duration with AVplayer - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm trying to get my audio file duration to display on my app but my code always return 0. I hope there is a method that notifies me when the AVplayer has data from the file and then I can call my code after that to get the data. Any suggestions?

```
    func loadAudioUrl() {

    guard let url = URL(string: sampleShortAudioUrl) else {return}

    audioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)

    audioPlayer?.play()

    if let duration = audioPlayer?.currentItem?.duration{
        print(duration)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get duration, but you need to wait because content is loading. Your code assumes that it is loaded instantly.

You need to use AVPlayerItem with AVPlayer.
When AVPlayerItem status is ready to play, you can ask for duration. Complete code example is right from Apple here:
[AVPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem)

Answer (score -1):

You can't get duration from a remote audio url , you must store it's duration remotely in your database and grap it while listening or downloading . . .